# Not able to create Grafana dynamic dashboard on influxDB dot included measurement

Tags: influxdb, grafana, telegraf, grafana-templating

The situation is i'm using telegraph for sending data to influxDB and Grafana(5.1.3) to visualize.influxDB storing the data in below formate

```
api.service-v1.request.status.total
api.service-v1.response.size
api.service-v1.upstream_latency
api.service-v1.user.consumer-001.request.count
api.service-v1.user.consumer-001.request.status.200
api.service-v1.user.consumer-001.request.status.429
api.service-v1.user.consumer-001.request.status.499
api.service-v1.user.consumer-001.request.status.total
```

And I'm like to create a dynamic dashboard based on service, consumer, and its status and more metrics. Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

We have Find out the solution.
we can create a `$service` variable with query(show measurements;) and regex`(/.*api.([^.]*).*/)` to filter service name.

second variable for `$consumer` and query(show measurements;) with regex option`(/.*api.$service.user.([^.]*).*/)` these variable we can use to visualized graph using toggle edit mode in grafana.

Thanks